# JavaScript stops working on selectively refreshed sections one inside the other

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer

I have two sections, a header and a logo in my theme. The logo is inside the header. A control in the customizer is responsible to handle the alignment of the header through selective refreshing.

I also have the logo section powered by selective refreshing. But as soon as I modify the header alignment by the respective control in the customizer, the selective refresh arrow icon disappears from the logo section. Also the JavaScript for menus and buttons becomes dysfunctional.

Can someone give more insights on why this happens, and how to fix this problem?